# Including fontspec package makes text slightly bolder

Tags: fonts, formatting, fontspec, typography

Whenever I include the `fontspec` package in my document, all text gets slightly bolder. 
How do I archieve the old look with `fontspec`?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Without fontspec}\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\begin{document}
\textbf{With fontspec}\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem stays the same no matter if I compile with `LuaLaTex` or `XeLaTex`.

Comment: Both files are compiled with Xe/LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Yes. The problem occurs with both of them.

Comment: I have no problem with LuaLaTeX, both look the same. Maybe you should update your distribution?

Comment: in current (post 2015) releases the same fonts are used (earlier than that adding fontspec would have switched from computer modern to latin modern) which latex release have you got?

Comment: I do have TeX Live 2015 (LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0), so this may actually be the problem. I installed it via `apt-get`. How can I force an update to newer versions?

Comment: If I remember well, `fontspec`  uses `Latin Modern` by default. Try `\setmainfont{CMU Serif}`.

Comment: `\setmainfont{CMU Serif}` does not solve the issue with `LuaLaTex`.

With `XeLaTex`, the document doesn't even compile:
`Font EU1/CMUSerif(0)/m/n/10="CMU Serif:mapping=tex-text;" at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. [\setmainfont{CMU Serif}]`

Comment: @jmb To get the current version of texlive, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu

Comment: You can't update from tl 2015 to 2017 you need to just install tl2017, but then lualatex will default to latin modern (the slightly darker one) the old default of cmr as the default really makes no sense you extend tex to be a unicode system but default fonts only have 127 characters and don't even have accented latin letters.

Answer (score 1):

Open the PDF, which has been compiled *without* the package fontspec. Have a look into the Meta-Data. Many PDF-Viewers display the metadata after "Ctrl-d". Metadata include the fonts used in the document. Now you know the font names.

Then just use them with fontspec, `\setmainfont` whatever.

Updating to texlive 2017 (that is: installing texlive 2017) isn't done in ten minutes and under very unlucky circumstances you might have to change something in your document (the change isn't the problem, but to find out about it...).